# Is there a way to prevent minute input in a Time Input?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm currently building a tool to schedule tasks to run automatically in an Angular app, so I need the user to enter an hour for the task to execute, installing a package to just manage this input seems a bit too much, so I was wondering if there's a way to limit what the user can enter in an `<input type="time">`.

I've read about the `step` property, but this still allows users to edit the minutes manually. Granted, I will only save the hour the user inputs, but from a UX perspective, letting them select specific minutes while being irrelevant to the actual process is a bad thing.

```html
<input type="time"/>
```

Comment: Why not use a numeric field and limit it from 0 to 23?

Comment: @NicoHaase I thought about it, just didn't like the aesthetic of it, also considered a select with a display value like: `1:00pm` and the actual value being `13`, but wanted to know if the time input could allow the behavior I needed... Would you say these two are better options?

Answer (score 1):

With certain browsers, if you set the step to an hour, it will not let you set the minutes.

```html
<input type="time" id="time" step="3600"/>
```

Other option is setting onchange event and manually scrubbing the minutes from the input.

```js
document.getElementById("time").addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
  var match = this.value.match(/^(\d{2})/);
  if (match) this.value = match[1] + ":00";
});
```

```html
<input type="time" id="time" />
```

Or just make a select with the hours...

```js
function populateTimes () {
  var sel = document.getElementById("time");
  for (var i=0; i<24;i++) {
    var amPm = i < 12 ? "AM" : "PM";
    var hour = (i % 12 ? (i % 12): 12).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    var opt = new Option(hour + ":00 " + amPm, i + ":00");
    sel.appendChild(opt);
  }
}
populateTimes();
```

```html
<select id="time"></select>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still allows you to if you use the dropdown controls; even removing the minutes onchange might be awkward to the user, seems it is better to use a select with predefined options